# Add to cart when the user is not logged in

Tags: firebase, flutter, e-commerce

I use Flutter and Firebase, just ask myself how to allow users to add items to cart when they're not logged in yet and keep the cart when they logging in, anyone have an idea for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Firebase you'd typically start the user off with an [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) account. With that sort of account, Firebase generates a user ID (UID) for the user, without them having to enter any credentials. You then associate the cart/items with the UID, and then when you/they are ready to identify themselves, you can sign them in with another provider, and [link that to the anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

I've provided links to the documentation for Android developers above, but the same functionality is available in the FlutterFire libraries too. For example, [anonymous sign-in on Flutter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#anonymous-sign-in) is as simple as:

```
UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
```

Comment: MMM... Just to be sure, where am I supposed to put this code ?

Comment: Typically that's be in the main screen, or the first screen where you need a UID.

Answer (score 0):

you can store this data in a separate database *SQL lite as an example*